# Pagination in List Java Spring

Tags: java, spring, sorting, spring-data-jpa, pagination

I'm working on a Spring project where I have Tasks (id, name) and Assignments (task_id, name, ...). When I get the tasks I also get assigned task, but I was not able to implement a pagination system.

```java
public List<Tasks> getAllTasks() {
       List<Tasks> task = (List<Tasks>) taskRepository.findAll();
       return task;
   }
```

That's my current code. I want to display 10 items in each paginated side.

I tried something like that:

```java
   public Page<Tasks> getAllTasks(Long page, Long size){
       List<Tasks> tsk = (List<Tasks>) taskRepository.findAll();
     
       int start =  new PageRequest(page, size).getOffset();
       int end = (start + new PageRequest(page, size).getPageSize()) > tsk.size() ? tsk.size() : (start + new PageRequest(page, size).getPageSize());

       return new PageImpl<Tasks>(tsk.subList(start, end), new PageRequest(page, size), tsk.size());
   }
```

but it's not working.

My current JSON response is as follows:

```java
{
   id: 1,
   name: First Task
   assignments: [ 
        {
          id: 1,
          assignment_name: firstassignment
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          assignment_name: secondassignment
        }]
}
```

I also read that it doesn't need to be a List. I'm open for any ideas.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can create and send `pageable` as a parameter in `findAll` to get the data

```
public Page<Tasks> getAllTasks(int page, int size){
    Pageable pageable = PageRequest.of(page, size);
    return taskRepository.findAll(pageable);
}
```

A good article about Pagination in Spring Data JPA [here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-pagination-sorting)

Comment: Do I need to add something like that: Page<Tasks> findAll(Long page, Long size); to my Task Repository? Because I'm getting this error: no suitable method found for of(java.lang.Long,java.lang.Long)

Comment: Don't send `page` & `size` in `findAll()`, send `pageable` as parameter only. See the code in answer. Make sure you are extending `JpaRepository` in `Repository`

Comment: I have it like that right now: public List< Tasks > getAllTasks() {
  Pageable pageable = PageRequest.of(page, size);
  Page< Tasks > pagedData = taskRepository.findAll(pageable);
  return pagedData;
 }. But I'm still getting cannot find symbol page and size error

Comment: And I'm also getting this error: incompatible types: org.springframework.data.domain.Page<com.example.management.model.Tasks> cannot be converted to java.util.List<com.example.management.model.Tasks>

Comment: See the updated code. You are not taking page & size in method and sending Page data where return type List

Comment: How can I set the number of data I want to show in one page? I updated my endpoint to that: "/v1/getalltasks/{page}/{size}".

Comment: Now it's different question. Add the code of controllers with mapping and service  in question  to understand your problem

Comment: I figured it out. Thanks.

Comment: Hey. I just run into a problem that I didn't saw at first. The way I did it paginates through tasks, but I want to paginate through assignments. How can I do that?

Comment: You can do the same way for other entity also.

Answer (score 0):

```
public List<Tasks>getAllTasks(Long page, Long size) {
   Pageable taskPageable = new PageRequest.of(page, size);
   return taskRepository.findAll(pageable);
}
```

We can also directly get `List` object instead of `Page` object.